# using request api into a json file that i can iterate through

Tags: python, api, python-requests

ok so im using python 3

i was able to get the data of the api using print(endpoint.json())

but i want to make it readable with pandas, so i can iterate through it easier.

this is the code (keep in mind i discarded my own api key and im using rapid api as a resource (specificly the movie database)

```
import requests
import json
import pandas
url = "https://movies-tvshows-data-imdb.p.rapidapi.com/"

querystring = {"type":"get-popular-movies","page":"1","year":"2020"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "movies-tvshows-data-imdb.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': my key
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data=response.json()
df=pandas.read_json(data)
print(df)
```

i get this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Home\Documents\studying\newproject\newproject.py", line 15, in <module>
    df=pandas.read_json(data)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 199, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 593, in read_json
    filepath_or_buffer, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 243, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case data is a dict.

So, try with:

```
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: how can i take it dataframe and insert into a text file? it says i cannot since its a dateframe

Comment: the dataframe is suited to CSV file. so once you save that in a variable called df you can do df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv')